# Discover where Bob is sleeping using hidden Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-process

Bob lives in four different houses $A, B, C$ and $D$ that are connected like the following graph shows:

[image]

Bob likes to sleep in any of his houses, but they are far apart so he only sleeps in a house adjacent to the one in which he slept the previous night. To clarify, this means that if Bob slept in house $A$ on night $1$, he may sleep in house $A$, $B$ or $C$ on night $2$ (not house $D$). The probability of each case is the same (one third); on each day, Bob takes a random walk from where stayed the previous night (and he might stay put).

Now Bob is a wanted criminal so on a given night the FBI would like to estimate where Bob is sleeping. Data from a satellite gives us the following probabilities of where Bob is sleeping on night $1$ and night $2$ (and any subsequent nights):

```
         Night 1   Night 2   ...
House A  0.8       0.05      ...
House B  0.1       0.4       ...
House C  0.05      0.05      ...
House D  0.05      0.5       ...
```

**How can we use this data to calculate the probability of where Bob was sleeping on night $2$, for example calculating the probability Bob slept in house A?** Could we use that method iteratively to calculate where Bob was sleeping on night $n$ if we continue to receive satellite data for each night?

Note: I made up this problem to understand better how hidden Markov chains work because I am interested in seeing the calculations on a concrete example. Many thanks for any input.

Comment: If you have obtained the probabilities for Night 1, then the probabilities for Night 2 are not arbitrary but they follow from the Markov Chain. Your data is inconsistent.

Comment: @leonbloy I believe you misunderstand. We have not calculated the probabilities for Night $2$, the data in the table is only what the satellite tells us. The problem is to calculate the real probability of where Bob is sleeping on night 2, taking into account the satellite data from night $1$ and $2$.

Comment: You are not formulating the problem rightly then. Either the columns are $p(x_n)$ or not. See my answer.

Comment: @leonbloy I read your answer. I still fail to see how I formulated my question incorrectly aside from using the tag "markov-chains" instead of "hidden-Markov-chains" (the latter does not exist unfortunately). If you understand the problem now and feel like the question can be edited to be easier to understand, feel free.

Comment: I've already answered. I give up.

Comment: @leonbloy You seem to fail completely to understand my comments. Your answer says "This is known as a Hidden Markov Chain (or Model), it's a more complex model than the plain Markov Chain, and its math is more difficult". Well yes it is a complex model and yes the math is difficult, but this is nevertheless my question and your answer does not contain a solution to the problem.

Comment: Lookup "Viterbi" or "Dynamic programming"

Comment: @leonbloy Now I have received an answer to the question, does the method look correct to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far no one has given an answer to the problem containing a solution, so I will post what I believe to be the solution.

We assume a uniform distribution initially, so the actual probabilities at night $1$ equal exactly the value in the table for the first night. Next step is to calculate for each house $k = \{A, B, C, D \} $ the following value:

$ S_2(i) \cdot \sum_{i \in N(k)} \frac{S_{1}(i)}{n(i)+1}$

where $N(k)$ is the set of neighbours of $k$ in addition to $k$ itself, $S_x(i)$ is the satellite probability of Bob sleeping at location $i$ on day $x$, and $n(i)$ is the number of neighbours of $i$. The reason this formula is relatively simple is because Bob takes a random walk at every night with each of his options equally likely - if he had a preference for one house over another, the above formula would be more complicated.

We begin by calculating the formula for $k=A$ and get $0.05 \cdot (0.05/(2+1) + 0.1/(2+1) + 0.8/(2+1)) = 0.0158$. The values for $k=B, k=C$ and $k=D$ can be found likewise to be $0.1267, 0.0158, 0.0333$. Normalizing, we find that the sum of all four values is $0.1917$, so the true probability that Bob is sleeping in house A on night $2$ is $0.0158/0.1917 = 8.2 \%$, and likewise the other probabilities for $B$, $C$ and $D$ are $66.1 \%$, $8.2 \%$ and $17.4\%$ respectively.

We perform a short sanity check and see that the probabilities correspond roughly with what we would expect; it seems most likely that Bob was indeed sleeping in house $B$, with $D$ being the next-most likely candidate, and $A$ and $C$ should be equally unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to update probability of Bob given satellite measurements.

The state of Bob at time $k$ is given by $x_{k}$. The measurement of a satellite is $y_{k}$. Since no prior information is given, we initialize with a uniform distribution
$$ \text{for } i={A,B,C,D},\,\, p(x_{0}=i|y_{0})=1/4.$$

Now that we have initialized, let's use Baye's rule to get $p(x_{1}=i|y_{0},y_{1})$. I'm only going to do this for i=A. Baye's rule yields

$$ p(x_{1}=A|y_{0},y_{1}) = \frac{p(x_{1}=A \cap y_{1}|y_{0})}{p(y_{1}/y_{0})}. $$
Now we just fill in the blanks. First, I like to calculate my "prediction", which is

$$ p(x_{1}=A | y_{0}) = \sum_{x_{0}\in{A,B,C,D}} P(x_{1}=A|x_{0})P(x_{0}|y_{0}).$$

Assuming bob is equally likely to stay in the house, or go to an adjacent house, this value is  3*(1/3)*1/4 = 1/4, and for this iteration at least, the prediction for other states is the same value. Now let's take a look at the Baye's Rule equation we outlined earlier

$$ p(x_{1}=A \cap y_{1}|y_{0}) = p(y_{1}|x_{1}=A)p(x_{1}=A|y_{0})=1/5$$

Finally,

$$ p(y_{1}/y_{0}) =  \sum_{x_{1}\in{A,B,C,D}} p(y_{1}/x_{1})p(x_{1}/y_{0}). $$

This comes out to be 1/4. Finally,

$$ p(x_{1}=A|y_{0},y_{1}) = \frac{1/5}{1/4} = 4/5. $$

Comment: Thank you. I am currently analyzing your answer to try to understand everything.

Comment: Is $p(x_1=A|y_0,y_1)$ the odds that Bob is sleeping in house $A$ on night $2$ or night $1$?

Comment: $p(x1=A|y0,y1)$ is the probability that Bob is in house A at time 1 given satellite measurements at time 0 AND time 1. I have not calculated $p(x2=A|y0,y1,y2)$, which is taking into account satellite measurements at time 2. I guess I should say that time 2 means night 2.

Comment: Alright, but I was in fact asking for the probability where Bob is on night $2$. :-) I might be wrong, but it seems trivial to me to calculate the probability that Bob sleeps in house $A$ on night $1$; it must match exactly the data given in the table (like your answer does) since we can assume that we initialize with uniform distribution in the beginning. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: The only reason that the probability matches what happens on night 1 is because I have assumed a uniform probability to start with. If you don't choose those, you won't get the same result. I only did night 1 because the procedure for night 2 is identical. I'm leaving it to you to use what I have provided to calculate the result for night 2.

Comment: Alright then, but in that case I would appreciate if you could clarify your calculations a little bit: how do you get that the product of the two probabilities in your fourth equation equals $1/5$ for example?

Comment: I assume that you get it by multiplying $0.8$ and $1/4$? Then we should, by doing the same calculations, get that $p(x_2=A|y_0,y_1,y_2) = (0.8*0.05)/((1/3)*0.8+(1/3)*0.1+(1/3)*0.05) = 0.126$, but this does not feel correct, especially considering that we will get the same value for $p(x_2=B|y_0,y_1,y_2)$

Answer (score 0):

If $K \in \{ A, B, C, D \}$, I write $K_n$ for the event 'Bob is in K on night n'.
Then what you have is:

\begin{align*}
P[A_{n+1}] &= P[A_{n+1} \cap A_n] + P[A_{n+1} \cap B_n] + P[A_{n+1} \cap C_n] + P[A_{n+1} \cap D_n] \\
&= P[A_{n+1} \mid A_n] P[A_n] + P[A_{n+1} \mid B_n] P[B_n] + P[A_{n+1} \mid C_n] P[C_n] + P[A_{n+1} \mid D_n] P[D_n] \\ 
&= P[A_n]/3 + P[B_n]/3 + P[C_n]/3 + 0. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if I understand your formula correctly, in order to calculate the odds on night $n+1$ you do not take into consideration the satellite data that we have collected about night $n+1$, only the data we have collected from night $n$. So in the example that I gave, you only use the satellite data from night 1 and not night 2; this cannot give us the complete answer using all available data.

Answer (score -3):

You may want to look at this.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm

Comment: I've been reading this link (it was suggested in the comment) but I don't fully understand the concept. If you can update your answer to show how you would use the algorithm to solve this particular problem, I'll accept your answer.